# Should I say "slipped out/off the clothesline" or "slipped from the clothesline"?

Tags: word-choice

What the correct option?

Example sentence:

> Look, this is exactly what happened. I was hanging my laundry on the
>   clothesline, there was a gust of wind, and my favorite T-shirt---the
>   one that says, 'Love Life'---**slipped out/from/off the clothesline.**

Comment: An alternative: blew off or even flew off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The boy **slipped out of or from the room**  when his mother wasn't looking.

  versus
- The shirt **slid off** the clothesline as it was not securely pinned to it.

Another example:

**A person slips out of or from a place**.

**A thing or person slides off** where it is.

**slip out** implies a person doing something stealthily. **Slide off** describes the manner in which a  person or thing moves off a thing. For a person, it can be involuntary or voluntary. The verb is slide, slid.

Answer (score 1):

*Slipped  out* implies the T-shirt is in the line, which is incorrect.

*Slipped from* implies the T-shirt and the line were initially in the same location, however does not explain how.

*Slipped off* implies the T-shirt was initially **ON** the line, which is the best usage.

Hope that helps!